# Не работает вызов jquery функции с помощью onChange

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не работает вызов функции с помощью onChange="calculate()". В консоли никаких ошибок вообще нет. До того как добавил консрукцию jQuery(document).ready(function($) выдавало $ is not a function

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    function calculate(){
         //тут код функции
    }
})
```

Comment: добавьте библиотеку `jquery`

Comment: а зачем вы вообще добавили эту конструкцию? и на что именно ругалось до добавления?

Comment: Ругалось на $ is not a function. А jquery и так есть на сайте

Comment: `onChange="calculate()"` вы добавляете в качестве аттрибута? Если так, то ошибка ожидаема. Вы прячете определение `calculate()` в локальную область видимости, а потом пытаетесь вызвать ее из глобальной. Рекомендую обрботчик "навесить" через `$(селектор).on('change', calculate)`

Comment: приведите код полностью. какой смысл объявлять функцию внутри события? вы же понимаете, что у нее есть область видимости.

Comment: @tutankhamun ожидаема, но не та, о которой вы пишите. Ожидаемо, что будет показано "неизвестная функция calculate", а пишет, как утверждается, `$ is not ...`.

Comment: @teran Я про текущую редакцию вопроса. Как я вижу, раньше ругалось из-за того что `jQuery` подключен с `noConflict()`, а внутри `calculate()`, были вызовы с `$`. Потом `calculate()` стала локальной

Answer (score 0, accepted):

За неимением подробностей в тексте вопроса, побробуем телепатию. Итак: сначала ругалось на `$`, потом просто не стало вызываться.

Пока вывод такой: `jQuery` подключен c `noConflict()` (Wordpress?). В функции `calculate()` есть вызовы методов `$`.

Как решить

**Малой кровью:**

1. Убираем `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {})`
2. В начало фнукции `calculate()` пишем `let $ = jQuery;` (или `var $ = jQuery;` если браузер очень старый)

**Правильным способом:**

1. Оставляем `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {})` (можно написать короче `jQuery(function($) {})`)
2. Устанавливаем обработчик через `$(селектор).on('change', calculate);`. Эта строка должна быть после определения функции `calculate()`.

Нужно еще учитывать, вы устанавливаете обработчик на элементе, который постоянно присутствует на странице или появляется там как результат других функций. В первом случае указанные изменения должны помочь. Во втором случае правильный способ потребует установки обработчика после появления элемента на странице

Answer (score 0):

Можете обращаться по классу или по `id` элемента. 
В функцию либо передавайте параметр, либо оставляйте пустым. 
Не стоит передавать символ `$`
Пример, как это работает:

```js
    $('#bum').on('click', function () {
        function calculate(){
            //тут код функции
        }
        console.log('123');
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bum">Парам Пам Пам</div>
```